# C Programming Registers Structure

Tags: c, function, hex

Trying to create a registers structure on a 64 bit machine and extract it. There are 7 registers in total, 2 registers are 4 bits while 3 registers are 8 bits and last 2 are 16 bits. How would I be able to create a registers structure and extract it. Using these functions.

```
RegisterFrame create_registers(...?) {???}
```

```
??? extract_registers(RegisterFrame, ...) {???}
```

My first guess was using pack and unpack

`RegisterFrame pack(uint64_t a1,uint64_t a2, uint64_t b0, uint64_t b1, uint64_t b2, uint64_t c1, uint64_t c2);
RegisterFrame unpack(uint64_t a1,uint64_t *a2, uint64_t *b0, uint64_t *b1, uint64_t *b2, uint64_t *c1, uint64_t *c2;`

But this was wrong cause we were required to use bit operations:

I thought

```
RegisterFrame create_register(uint64_t a1,uint64_t a2, uint64_t b0, uint64_t b1, uint64_t b2, uint64_t c1, uint64_t c2){
uint64_t retval = 0x0, tempa1, tempa2, tempb0, tempb1, tempb2, tempc1, tempc2
tempa1 = (a1&0xffffffff)
tempa2 = (a2&0xffffffff) << 4
tempb0 = (b0&0xffffffff) << 8
tempb1 = (b1&0xffffffff) << 8
tempb2 = (b2&0xffffffff) << 8
tempc1 = (c1&0xffffffff) << 16
tempc2 = (c2&0xffffffff) << 16
retval = tempa1|tempa2|tempb0|tempb1|tempb2|tempc1|tempc2;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: that's a lot of arguments, consider grouping them together in a `struct`.

Comment: So the question is basically, how to pack all of these 7 variables into one 64-bit variable?

Comment: Question is to create and extract the register structure.

Comment: If I use struct then wouldn't there be no use for the RegisterFrame create_registers(...?) {???}.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking either. For starters, please edit your question and supply a definition for `RegisterFrame`.

Comment: You're not masking your input values correctly.

Comment: What is a `RegisterFrame`?  It is not a standard type, and its definition is relevant to the question.

Comment: What type is `extract_registers()` supposed to return?  This is not something that we can decide for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. The definition of `RegisterFrame` is not showed neither was the output of the last try you thought.

...but assuming that you are trying to 'pack' values from different sizes into a `'uint64_t'` variable, your tentative was few issues:

First: `0xffffffff` is a 32bit value, not a 64bit value.

Second: lets say *tempa* contains *4bits*, *tempb* contains *8bits* and *tempc* contains *16bits*, but they are all uint64_t variables.

Third: if you want to pack {tempa0,tempa1,tempb0,tempb1,tempb2,tempc0,temp1} your mistake not masking the actual size you wanted (32bits for all the cases instead 4,8,16bits) and not rotating correctly (if you rotate both values `<<4` and then use bit-wise or `|` you are basically 'ORing' the values between bit[7:4], for instance)

probably (not tested) what you wanted is something like the code bellow:

`RegisterFrame create_register(uint64_t a1,uint64_t a2, uint64_t b0, uint64_t b1, uint64_t b2, uint64_t c1, uint64_t c2){
    uint64_t retval = 0x0, tempa1, tempa2, tempb0, tempb1, tempb2, tempc1, tempc2
    tempa1 = (a1&0xf)  << 0
    tempa2 = (a2&0xf)  << 4
    tempb0 = (b0&0xff) << 8
    tempb1 = (b1&0xff) << 16
    tempb2 = (b2&0xff) << 24
    tempc1 = (c1&0xffff) << 32
    tempc2 = (c2&0xffff) << 48
    retval = tempa1|tempa2|tempb0|tempb1|tempb2|tempc1|tempc2;
    return retval;
}`